# Is the discount factor $v=(1+i)^{-1}$, where $i$ is an interest rate, always annualized?

Tags: finance

So I was under the impression that **the discount factor $v$ is always annualized**. But as I work on [this problem for an $n$-year bond](http://math.illinoisstate.edu/krzysio/KO-FM-Exercise144.pdf), it seems not to be the case, as they arrive at this conclusion for the present value of some semiannual coupons (sorry not sure how to do angle-n notation):

$a_{2n}=\frac{1-v^{2n}}{i^{(2)}}$

So the $n$-year bond has $2n$ payment/conversion periods, which is fine, but **doesn't $v^{2n}$ imply that $v$ is a semiannual discount factor, not an annual one?** It seems to me the line of thinking goes more like this...

$a_{2n}=\frac{1-(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^{-2n}}{i^{(2)}} 
= \frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i^{(2)}} 
= \frac{1-v^{n}}{i^{(2)}}$

On the other hand, the problem defines $i$ to be the semiannual yield rate, which is a bit unusual for these problems where $i$ is almost always the effective annual rate. So is the period of $v$ to be understood in terms of how we define $i$? And if so, can I take that to the bank, so to speak? Works every time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears that $v$ can indeed be a semiannual discount factor, and that it depends on the period defined for $i$. This problem defines $i$ to be a semiannual rate, and so $v$ follows suit.

This may be unique to this particular type of problem on Exam FM.